# How to run the Docker image using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have Flask application running under Docker Compose with 2 containers one for Flask and the other one for Nginx.

I am able to run the Flask successfully using `docker-compose up --build -d` command in my local machine.

What I want is, to save the images into .tar.gz file and move them to the production server and run them automatically. I have used below Bash script to save the Flask and Nginx into one image successfully.

```
#!/bin/bash

for img in $(docker-compose config | awk '{if ($1 == "image:") print $2;}'); do
  images="$images $img"
done

docker save $images | gzip -c > flask_image.tar.gz
```

I then moved this image `flask_image.tar.gz` to my production server where Docker installed and used below command to load the image and run the containers.

```
docker load -i flask_image.ta.gz
```

This command loaded every layer and loaded the image into my production server. But containers are not up which is expected, since I used only load command.

My question is, is there any command that can load the image and up the containers automatically?

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:

  api:
    container_name: flask
    image: flask_img
    restart: always
    build: ./app
    volumes:
      - ~/docker_data/api:/app/uploads
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
    command: gunicorn -w 1 -b :5000 wsgi:app -t 900

  proxy:
    container_name: nginx
    image: proxy_img
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ~/docker_data/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
    ports:
      - "85:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Comment: Images are already composed of tarballs but have extra data too.  Instead of trying to tar an image, have you considered pushing your images to a docker registry?  Docker hub is one option, google cloud and aws and azure also have registries to use if you're on those clouds.  As a DevOps engineer I would consider it crazy to try to distribute docker images any other way.

Comment: Can you please update some links on how to do it with docker registry. FYI, I have pushed my image to docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention you already are pushing the docker image to Docker Hub, that means the image has a dockerhub tag that you can use to pull it also.

Usually I use something like this to pull images that are on a registry:

`docker run --rm -d --restart=always -p 80:8080 my-dockerhub-user/my-image-name:my-tag`

which would run the container in daemon mode and restart if it were to fail.  That's just an example; you'd want the ports to align with whatever flask is listening on (`8080` in my example) and and the what your server should be listening on (`80` in my example).

The server will automatically pull the image down and run it.  You can use tags to promote new images, but in that case you'll have to kill the old container as well.

Comment: since i am using flask and nginx, and mapping the ports. I am not sure If this idea works. I have updated my docker-compose.yml file